firstname and lastname not displaying from one file to another
Though it doesn't tell me that there are errors, the firstname and lastname doesn't show up in my QRPageRegistered
This my code for the ManifestInformationWidgets.dart where I'm getting the firtname and lastname.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:namer_app/Passenger_Widgets/PRFAlertDialog.dart';
import 'package:namer_app/Passenger_Widgets/DropBoxes.dart';
import 'package:philippines_rpcmb/philippines_rpcmb.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:namer_app/Passenger_Widgets/CustomTextboxes.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'QRPageRegistered.dart';

class TextBoxContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final SharedPreferences prefs;
  const TextBoxContainer({Key? key, required this.prefs}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextBoxContainerState createState() => _TextBoxContainerState();
}

class _TextBoxContainerState extends State<TextBoxContainer> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool isEditing = false;
  bool isEnabled = false; 
  Region? region;
  Province? province;
  Municipality? municipality;
  String? barangay;
  String? selectedGender;

  late TextEditingController _firstNameController;
  late TextEditingController _middleInitialController;
  late TextEditingController _lastNameController;
  late TextEditingController _contactNumberController;
  late TextEditingController _professionController;
  late TextEditingController _ageController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _firstNameController =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.prefs.getString('firstName') ?? '');
    _middleInitialController = TextEditingController(
        text: widget.prefs.getString('middleInitial') ?? '');
    _lastNameController =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.prefs.getString('lastName') ?? '');
    _contactNumberController = TextEditingController(
        text: widget.prefs.getString('contactNumber') ?? '');
    _professionController =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.prefs.getString('profession') ?? '');
    _ageController =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.prefs.getString('age') ?? '');

    selectedGender = widget.prefs.getString('gender');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _firstNameController.dispose();
    _middleInitialController.dispose();
    _lastNameController.dispose();
    _contactNumberController.dispose();
    _professionController.dispose();
    _ageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _enableEditing() async {
    if (!isEditing) {
      PRFAlertDialog(context, (success) {
        if (success) {
          setState(() {
            isEditing = true;
            isEnabled = true;  
          });
        }
      });
    } else if (isEditing) {
      if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
        final response = await Supabase.instance.client
            .from('User')
            .update({
              'first_name': _firstNameController.text,
              'middle_initial': _middleInitialController.text,
              'last_name': _lastNameController.text,
              'phone': _contactNumberController.text,
              'profession': _professionController.text,
              'age': _ageController.text,
            })
            .eq('email', widget.prefs.getString('email') ?? '')
            .select();
        if (response.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            isEditing = false;
            isEnabled = false;  
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void handleGenderSelected(String? gender) {
    setState(() {
      selectedGender = gender;
    });
  }

void navigateToQRPageRegistered() {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => HomePage(
        firstName: _firstNameController,
        lastName: _lastNameController,
      ),
    ),
  );
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  MIWCustomTextBox(
                    textController: _firstNameController,
                    isEnabled: isEnabled,
                    hintText: 'Enter firstname',
                    labelText: 'First name',
                    containerWidth: 190,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter your first name';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  MIWCustomTextBox(
                    textController: _middleInitialController,
                    isEnabled: isEnabled,
                    hintText: 'Enter MI',
                    labelText: 'Middle Initial',
                    containerWidth: 80,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter your middle initial';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            MIWCustomTextBox(
                textController: _lastNameController,
                isEnabled: isEnabled,
                hintText: 'Enter Surname',
                labelText: 'Surname',
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your surname';
                  }
                  return null;
                }),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            LocationDropdowns(
              isEnabled: isEnabled,
              onRegionChanged: (selectedRegion) {
                setState(() {
                  region = selectedRegion;
                  province = null;
                  municipality = null;
                  barangay = null;
                });
              },
              onProvinceChanged: (selectedProvince) {
                setState(() {
                  province = selectedProvince;
                  municipality = null;
                  barangay = null;
                });
              },
              onMunicipalityChanged: (selectedMunicipality) {
                setState(() {
                  municipality = selectedMunicipality;
                  barangay = null;
                });
              },
              onBarangayChanged: (selectedBarangay) {
                setState(() {
                  barangay = selectedBarangay;
                });
              },
              region: region,
              province: province,
              municipality: municipality,
              barangay: barangay,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            MIWCustomTextBox(
                textController: _contactNumberController,
                isEnabled: isEnabled,
                hintText: 'Enter Contact Number',
                labelText: 'Contact Number',
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your contact number';
                  }
                  return null;
                }),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            MIWCustomTextBox(
                textController: _professionController,
                isEnabled: isEnabled,
                hintText: 'Enter Profession',
                labelText: 'Profession',
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your profession';
                  }
                  return null;
                }),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  MIWCustomTextBox(
                    textController: _ageController,
                    isEnabled: isEnabled,
                    hintText: 'Enter Age',
                    labelText: 'Age',
                    containerWidth: 135,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter your age';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  GenderDropBox(
                    onGenderChanged: handleGenderSelected,
                    isEnabled: isEnabled,
                    selectedGender: selectedGender,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            EditButton(
              isEditing: isEditing,
              toggleEditing: _enableEditing,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EditButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isEditing;
  final VoidCallback toggleEditing;

  const EditButton(
      {Key? key, required this.isEditing, required this.toggleEditing})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 280,
      height: 50,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: toggleEditing,
        child: Text(isEditing ? "CONFIRM" : "EDIT"),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4FCAD2),
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF33385F),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



This is my QRPageRegistered.dart code where I want the firstname and lastname to be displayed:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? origin;
  final String? destination;
  final String? firstName;
  final String? lastName;

  HomePage({
    super.key,
    this.origin,
    this.destination,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
  });

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        debugPrint('Received First Name: ${widget.firstName}');
    debugPrint('Received Last Name: ${widget.lastName}');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('E-Ticket'),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7ADFC1),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [Color(0xFF7ADFC1), Color(0xFF21A5D1)],
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 350,
                height: 550,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    QrImageView(
                      data: widget.destination ?? '',
                      version: QrVersions.auto,
                      size: 300.0,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text(
                      '${widget.firstName ?? ''} ${widget.lastName ?? ''}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'Student',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text(
                      '${widget.origin ?? ''} - ${widget.destination ?? ''}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    const Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Total Fee:',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '₱0.00',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showConfirmationDialog(context);
                },
                child: const Text('Complete Transaction'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showConfirmationDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: const Text('Do you want to complete the transaction?'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('No'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Yes'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


I've been trying to edit the constructor in the Homepage part as well as the parameter names on both codes but it either shows error/s or it doesn't show anything in QRPageRegistered. I already changed it to String type as well.

Instead of passing the TextEditingControllers, try to read their values and pass first and last name as strings. Add print or debugPrint statements to see their values in both widgets.

@PeterKoltai I used:
void navigateToQRPageRegistered() {
String firstName = _firstNameController.text;
String lastName = _lastNameController.text;
debugPrint('First Name: $firstName');
debugPrint('Last Name: $lastName');
}
and it just says null in the debug console

How do you assign the controllers in the MIWCustomTextBox widgets?

Are you sure you are calling navigateToQRPageRegistered() this method because I am unable to find this function call. Please make sure you are called that function and still not get value let me know I will prepare proper demo.

you are using
final TextEditingController? firstName;
final TextEditingController? lastName; 

if you need to use the TextEditingController you need to use firstName.text but if you do not need the TextEditingController you can change the type of firstName and lastName to String type and use it.

I tried changing it to a String type but it still don't show the firstname and lastname.
